# Having problem running electron on Raspberry Pi4. It works well on Raspberry Pi3

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, electron

I have a simple hello world Electron App running on a variety of machines which include Windows, Ubuntu, and Raspberry Pi3.  It however does not work on Raspberry Pi4.  Has any body solved this please?

```
> electron@7.1.7 postinstall /home/pi/node_modules/electron
> node install.js

(node:6353) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: HTTPError: Response code 404 (Not Found)
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/home/pi/node_modules/got/source/as-stream.js:35:24)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at module.exports (/home/pi/node_modules/got/source/get-response.js:22:10)
    at ClientRequest.handleResponse (/home/pi/node_modules/got/source/request-as-event-emitter.js:155:5)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:300:26)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:215:7)
    at ClientRequest.origin.emit (/home/pi/node_modules/@szmarczak/http-timer/source/index.js:37:11)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (_http_client.js:583:27)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:115:17)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:456:22)
(node:6353) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:6353) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN app@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN app@1.0.0 No repository field.

+ electron@7.1.7
added 85 packages from 91 contributors and audited 102 packages in 10.15s

2 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Any tips, pointers or suggestions are welcome.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: 404 looks like a network problem. Try to fetch the URL with `curl` and check if it works.